# Using a 36V battery with step up converter for 48v kit

Tags: batteries, step-up

I have an e-bike motor ( bbs02 48v 750watts ) which requires a 48v battery. I also have a 36v 13ah e-bike battery. Opening the battery and changing cells connection to make it 48 takes a lot of effort.

Is it a bad idea to use a step-up converter? I have a dc-dc converter which claims to have 95% efficiency. Any downside of using one?

If I would step up the 36v input to 50.92 volts using a step converter, will the e-bike motor meter still read the battery as full? Even if the battery goes below 50%, would the output of the step-up converter still be 50.92 volts? Or would the voltage drop?

Comment: Is that DC/DC converter rated for 750W?

Comment: This is a bad idea, and will probably fail for one practical reason or another, especially with regard to the less usual circumstances the system can find itself in.  As an example, consider that regenerative braking (either designed or accidental) would fail entirely, quite possibly destroying components in the process.  In theory a system which worked this way could be engineered, but the components would have to be designed specifically for this use.  In practice, the battery, controller, and motor are instead matched to each other.

Comment: The startup currents of the motor-----may be more than any cheap DC_DC converter can handle.

Comment: Many e-bike motors have freewheel so they can't regen. My first had a motorised front wheel with freewheel for normal cycling. My current one has a Panasonic under-pedals motor which drives the chain. This freewheels on the rear sprocket as a normal bike. You'd need to check that but overall this looks like a bad idea. One big downside is that the motor controller won't know when the battery is flat until you've over-discharged it.

Comment: In regards to the above comments, you would need a MPU programmed to monitor battery voltage, and a charger. Adding useful regenerative braking may take a machine shops help-and expense. Re-think this idea.

Comment: There is no question that this is possible, however I would like to add weight of the voltage converter and current rating of the battery pack to the list of concerns.  Such a device would likely require substantial inductor weight and substantial cooling.  In a form with adequate tolerances it just might cost more than the proper battery.  Your source 36V battery would also have to be rated for 4/3 the current plus losses that the 48V battery would be rated for.

Answer (score 2):

While yes this could work, it's a very poor solution.

As the battery gets drained, its voltage will go down, which means a higher load is needed to keep the same output voltage and current. Efficiency will drop at the battery and at the converter.

Is the 36V battery able to produce at least 22 Amps? Or higher as the voltage drops, ~25A at 32V? Assuming the input voltage and current is within range of the converter's output capability, the output should stay the same as the input voltage goes down as long as the input current can keep up.

How will you deal with the heat at the converter? Assuming 95% at 36V in and 48V 15.6A out, that's 750W / .95 = 789W - 750W = 39W in waste heat. That's an immense amount of power to manage. You'd basically be shining an entire halogen bulb right between your legs/butt. Is your converter rated for that, proper heat sinking?

This isn't even considering inrush or stall currents. The motor is most efficient at speed, but starting from a standstill will make it draw much more as it overcomes mechanical and electrical inertia. Your converter and battery will both need to support whatever current those conditions require.

As for the battery monitor, you will need to hack in a middle man circuit to scale the voltage or battery pack sensor reading. A microcontroller could do that, and while it's not trivial, it's comparatively easy compared to the above. Some coding and some basic electronics needed.

In short, this is an impractical idea that has way too many challenges. Trade the battery or motor for an appropriate voltage one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a bad idea.

You don’t know what the motor/battery controller expects and it would be hard piece of engineering to get 95% efficiency over a broad range of load currents.